# How to add multiple fields to NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I want to search an array of users on the first or last name by using a query string. Below is the predicate, but I'm getting an exception.

```
NSPredicate *sortingPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(User.first contains[c] %@) OR (User.last contains[c] %@)", keyword, keyword];
```

Exception:

```
exception   NSException *   name:@"NSUnknownKeyException" reason:@"[<User 0x12911980> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key User."   0x13653620
```

Comment: Is that even working with one of them? It looks like the issue is with "User". Did you mean `"(first contains[c] %@) OR (last contains[c] %@)"`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must not include the *entity name* in the predicate, only the *key* (or key path):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(first CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (last CONTAINS[c] %@)", keyword, keyword]
```

***Update:*** "FIRST" and "LAST" have a special meaning in a predicate, they are used to
specify the first or last element in an array (see [Aggregate Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215891) in the "Predicate Programming Guide").

This ambiguity can be avoided by using the `%K` format for expanding the property keys:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (%K CONTAINS[c] %@)",
                                   @"first", keyword, @"last", keyword];
```

Comment: exception NSException * name:@"NSInvalidArgumentException" reason:@"Can't use in/contains operator with collection FIRST (not a collection)" 0x138ce130

Comment: @WilliamFalcon: How are the properties first/last defined? What type do they have? What `keyword` contain?

Comment: @property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *first;//    
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *last;//

Comment: @WilliamFalcon: Is the a predicate for a Core Data fetch request? Or are you filtering an array of custom objects?

Comment: filtering array of custom objects

Comment: @WilliamFalcon: OK. This *should* work, but I will test it right now.

Comment: @WilliamFalcon: I could reproduce your problem. It seems that "first" and "last" have a special meaning in a predicate (I still have to find out why). Renaming the properties to "firstName", "lastName" solved it and works as expected.

Comment: I figured it was something like that. I can't really rename it since it is system wide... I'll look into another way (maybe escaping it or something...).

Comment: @WilliamFalcon: I have updated the answer (there is a solution!)

Comment: Beat me to it haha. Here is a link to the documentation for the sake of completion... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Comment: Very Helpful!! Worked for me